How are Martin Buber and Emanuel Levinas received by the broader continental tradition
I’m curious to what extent are the Jewish continental philosophers Martin Buber and Emmanuel Levinas taken as influential  by the broader secular or Christian continental philosophy world? I ask because even though they are strongly indebted to Jewish tradition, they seem to engage with secular and Christian (especially existentialist) continental philosophers like Martin Heidegger and Søren Kierkegaard quite a bit.

This is a good question, but as "taken as influential" has to be understood as an empirical question, you might want to set the standard of what you mean by "taken as influential" lest open your question up to the opinion-based VTC. Good luck!
